# Removing the [ OK ] From start_udev

Tags: fedora, udev, sysvinit

Under `/sbin/start_udev`, how can I remove the `[  OK  ]` so it's not printed?

I'm trying to change `/etc/rc.sysinit` to display the information I like, and I have managed to remove all the info output apart from the annoying `[  OK  ]`

Any ideas? I'm using Fedora 13

Comment: Be aware that if you're using Fedora, this is All Going Away with the advent of `systemd` in Fedora 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all controlled by `/etc/sysconfig/init`.

I'm pretty sure all you have to do is change it from

```
BOOTUP=color
```

to

```
BOOTUP=verbose
```

After doing that, it should change from something like:

```
Stopping udev:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting udev:                                             [  OK  ]
```

to

```
Stopping udev: udev
Starting udev:
```

Have a look at `/etc/init.d/functions` to see how that works.

`start_udev` calls `success` to print the `[  OK  ]` message, and `/etc/init.d/functions` is where `success` is defined.

Comment: I thin you sort of misunderstood me, im trying to have my own output, none of what linux shows, so i have managed to remove Stopping udev, by commenting it out, but still an ok apears

Comment: @whoami, `/sbin/start_udev` sources `/etc/init.d/functions`, which in turn calls `/etc/sysconfig/init` as @Mikel says. So this should work.